# Django Dynamic Template with Custom function problem

Tags: python, django

As I have using the django custom table for authentication and session id for setting the navbar action but not able to change with custom function able to find similar things but how i can write my custom function pls find

Code for userauth inbuilt management which i intent to change user.authenticated to a custom function

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
          {{user.username}}
          <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
{% else %}
 <li><a href="/login">Login/a></li>
 <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**                    {% if request.session.member_id %}
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{request.session.member_id}}
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'myaccount' %}">My Profile</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Sign Out</a>
```

-->
Guest Login–>-->
-->

```
                {% else %}
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    My Account
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'registration' %}">Sign Up</a>
               {% endif %}
```

I am Using session Id for verification is it safe for use ??